# How can I replace a variable inside an object?

Tags: php, oop, object, variables

I try to replace a variable inside my object method:

```
 $fieldname = "project";

 $test = $page->getTemplate()->getProject();
```

This is my approach:

```
 $test = $page->getTemplate()->'get'.$fieldname();
```

But I get the error message

> syntax error, unexpected ''get'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Answer (score 4):

```
$test = $page->getTemplate()->{'get' . $fieldname}();
```

Also, I will mention that although `getproject` and `getProject` are the **same method**, this is not correct for **properties**.

Comment: Could this be solved like this?  `$insert = 'get'.ucwords($fieldname);
                $test = $page->getTemplate()->$insert();`

Comment: Sure, it could.